# In functional programming what is "currying"?

Tags: functional-programming, currying

Writing as an unreconstructed imperative & OO programmer...

Have messed about with Erlang and also Haskell lately. I like Erlang, not sure yet about Haskell. Functional seems more like math than programming, hope that makes sense. Functional programming seems very powerful.

Reading docs on the interwibble wrt functional programming I come across the word 'currying' constantly. I seem to be finding only docs that are somewhat over my head - much terminology that is not defined.

What is currying?

I have looked for similar already posted questions but did not find anything, so feel free to point me to established thread.