# Passing a function and one of its arguments to another function in Python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I am now trying to pass a multi-variable function `F(x, y, z)` as an argument of another function `G(F, x)` in Python.  As written, the two arguments in function G is the function F and one of F's variables x.  In other words, what I am trying to do is instead of passing F as a three-variable function, I'd rather pass it as a single variable function which depends only on x.  The values of y and z are already assigned before calling G.

In Matlab, this is done simply by:

```
G((@x) F(x, y, z));
```

I am wondering if there is something similar in Python? I have tried to search online but I am not very familiar with the English wording for this particular question so no luck.

Comment: Is G supposed to use the output of F, or will it execute F on its own?  It sounds like what you're asking for is called 'currying':  http://mtomassoli.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/currying-in-python/

Answer (score 5):

It may be also done with functools.partial

```
In [158]:from functools import partial

In [159]: adder_w = partial(adder, y=5, z=10)

In [160]: adder_w(2)
Out[160]: 17
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I've forgotten to include function *adder* copied (I am lazy :) )from the @thefourtheye's answer

```
def adder(x, y, z):
    return x + y + z
```

Comment: But we cannot reuse the partial function object, for different functions. :)

Comment: @thefourtheye, it is seldom that you will need such a flexible wrapper in real-life projects.

Answer (score 5):

lambda is suitable for this situation.

```
def G(func, x):
    return func(x)

def F(x, y, z):
    return x+y+z

print G(lambda x: F(x, 1, 2), 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with Python closures and [function currying technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352855/in-functional-programming-what-is-currying), like this

```
def adder(x, y, z):
    return x + y + z

def wrapper_g(y, z):
    def g(f, x, y = y, z = z):
        return f(x, y, z)  # By closure property, `f` accesses `y` and `z`
    return g

g = wrapper_g(5, 10)       # We are creating `g` with default parameters 5 and 10
print g(adder, 20)         # along with the third parameter 20, adder is called. 
print g(adder, 40)         # along with the third parameter 40, adder is called. 
print g(multiplier, 2)     # We can pass any function, which can act on 2 params.
print g(multiplier, 2, y = 3, z = 4) # We can dynamically alter the default param
```

**Output**

```
35
55
100
24
```

**Advantages:**

1. We can dynamically decide which function to be invoked
2. We even get to alter the default parameters, while calling.

Answer (score 1):

It can be as simple as this

```
def F(x,y,z):
  print "x=",x
  print "y=",y
  print "z=",z

def G(func,x):
  func(x,"G's Y", "G's Z")

G(F,"Main's X")
```