# haskell function invoke order

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm learning some haskell since this weekend, I found this language interesting, but also some syntaxs make me confused.

Like, `zip` is a function that take 2 list as parameters and then return a list of pairs.
if I invoke `zip [1,2,3] [3,2,1]` in `ghci` I got `[(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)]`. But if I say `(zip [1,2,3]) [3,2,1]` it returns the same result.

When I looked into the definition of the zip function using `:i zip`, I got `zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]  -- Defined in ‘GHC.List’`, from this it seems that `zip` is a function apply the first parmeter, return a function and then apply to the second parameter.

Another example is `elem`, `elem 1 [1,2,3]`, `(elem 1) [1,2,3]` and `` (1 `elem`) [1,2,3] `` return the same result.

So my question is if a function receive multiple parameters, how this function evaluate, process each parameter in order or just process all parameters in one time.

Comment: You can read `someFunc :: a -> b -> c` as `someFunc :: a -> (b -> c)`, which might help you to answer the question yourself.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352855/in-functional-programming-what-is-currying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(->)` is right associative¹, and that means that something like this:

```
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
```

is understood by GHC as:

```
zip :: [a] -> ([b] -> [(a, b)])
```

The latter helps you to see that when you call `zip` with one argument, you get a function back:

```
λ> :t zip [1, 2, 3]
zip [1, 2, 3] :: Num a => [b] -> [(a, b)]
```

This is called [`currying`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Currying), or partial application.

---

Notes

1. Right associative means that the operator groups to the right. A common example is the power operator `^`. In a power tower, this is evident:

   `λ> 2^2^2^2
   65536
   λ> 2^(2^(2^2))
   65536`

   If the power operator were left-associative, we would have:

   `λ> ((2^2)^2)^2
   256`

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought I found something big, but it turns out to be a common idea in haskell.I'll continue dive into it.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. Yes, currying is common and super-useful! You might consider accepting the answer if it answered you questions.

Comment: sorry man, I just realized I should accept a satisfied answer.